# Can I use a portable AC Inside my outdoor enclosed cabana for my massage therapy work during summer?

Tags: hvac, portable-ac

Can I use a portable AC Inside my outdoor enclosed cabana for my massage therapy work during summer? I was thinking putting the vent underneath one of the side panels. Probably need to duct tape the rest of the flappy walls to create a tight seal. I just need one side of the zipper to open for entrance.  Is this a stupid idea? I'm in san diego and humidity can be 60% so don't know if swamp cooler is good.

Comment: You can try, but it might not work very well. Houses normally have significant insulation in the walls, while your tent does not. It’s going to be letting in a lot more heat from the sun than a house would. You might find you need a significantly larger AC unit to keep your tent cool, compared to what a house room of the same size would need.

Comment: Yes, you can. We did a tent for a wedding party overflow. Downside is that it will likely run 100%, but as long as that's ok, it will keep it somewhat cooler in there. Better insulation or tightness will lower temp before it gets efficient enough to cycle on/off while holding a temp.

Comment: Dan that is a answer go ahead and make it one I agree it will help.

Comment: You **really, really want** a portable that has 2 hoses - inlet and outlet.   I know that seems *less* desirable and convenient, but it's because of a technical issue with the way A/C works. The hot air being ejected has to come from somewhere.  If it comes from a 2nd pipe, that works great.  Otherwise it is stolen from the room itself, which causes hot air from outside to be sucked into the room, which defeats the purpose of the A/C.